# How to acquire a lock and force release it after some time? Java

Tags: java, concurrency, deadlock

I have a problem with database and java threads deadlocks, so is it possible to set some time for java thread to be inside lock, and release it then, to prevent all system hang? By this trick I want to release lock in DB to return system to normal workflow and no matter that some query would fail...

Comment: IMO, you should consider identifying and fixing the root cause instead of hacking around the symptoms.

Comment: Spent a lot of time, but couldn't find the problem because this is very rare thing, and on local machine we could never reproduce :(

Comment: Is there a Java thread deadlock, or is there a database deadlock (or livelock)?

Comment: I just didn't know how to accept, wright now noticed this tick =) Will accept later... There is database deadlocks both with java. Some DB processes are in 'query in transaction' state for long time (hours and hours) and everything is hanging

Answer (score 0):

Try [`Statement.setQueryTimeout()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#setQueryTimeout%28int%29).

However, in most circumstances doing this should probably be considered a hack rather than a proper solution. As @lobster1234 has said, find and fix the root cause.

Comment: AFAIK query timeout isn't implemented on all JDBC drivers.

Answer (score 0):

If your database supports a (lock) wait timeout, make sure it is configured, or use the nowait option if available (which will immediately report a lock error)

Comment: Thanks for advice, will try to check this

Comment: I see that in postgresql lock wait timeout is not supported, only deadlock